# Как отследить по какому URL ушел пользователь с сайта?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cookie

Доброго времени суток! 
Пытаюсь сохранить через куки в БД информацию о пользователе (ИП,браузер,дату,ссылку перехода(куда?))
У меня есть страница на которую заходят пользователи и потом должны выбрать " перейти на сайт 1 " , " перейти на сайт рекламодателя","пойти в интернет (вбивают ссылку какую хотят)" . Мне нужно отследить их выбор и записать в БД

```
$ip = ip2long($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]); // Преобразуем IP в число , IP user
  $uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // Узнаём uri
  $ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; // Узнаём, откуда пришёл
  $date = date("d.m.Y || H:i:s"); // Берём текущее время
```

Не могу понять, как это сделать .

Comment: боюсь, что только написать ему письмо

Comment: что не можете довести до ума? получение времени? Какойто загадочный вопрос, и еще большую загадочность ему придают `...` в конце ;)

Comment: я не знаю, как мне отследить переход пользователя

Comment: Всеравно вопрос не понятен, расскажите подробнее. Или вам нужно отследить куда именно с вашего сайта он ушел?

Comment: У меня есть страница на которую заходят пользователи и потом должны выбрать " перейти на сайт 1 " , " перейти на сайт рекламодателя","пойти в интернет (вбивают ссылку какую хотят)" . Мне нужно отследить их выбор и записать в БД

Comment: Вы хотите отслеживать куда с вашего сайта пошел пользователь?! может стоит тогда изменить тему например так: "Как отследить по какому URL ушел пользователь"?! или же "Откуда пользователь попал на сайт"

Answer (score 2):

Всё просто:

1. Грубо

Привязываешь к ссылкам, по которым уходят пользователи, id. Ссылку и ID можно связать в mysql-таблице с двумя полями **('id', 'link')**. Простой способ, но пользователь, наведя на ссылку, будет видеть что-то типа **http://mysite.ru/go_away.php?id=343**. Что не есть хорошо, пользователь должен видеть куда идет.

2. Мягко

Как в прошлом случае, нам нужна табличка связывания ID и ссылки. Но только теперь мы пишем в **href** anchor-тэга реальную ссылку, но вешаем **onClick()** на этот тэг. А в обработчике запрещаем переход, и вместо него открываем нужную нам ссылку, через которую мы можем отследить, куда пошел пользователь. Если твой PHP-скрипт логирования пользователей не будет крашиться или по 2-3 секунды обрабатывать запрос, юзер даже не заметит, что сначала посетил твой скрипт, перед тем как попасть туда, куда он хотел

**Обновление**

Когда пользователь набирает в адресной строке, адрес отслеживать невозможно. Из комментария автора - "У меня есть страница на которую заходят пользователи и потом должны выбрать " перейти на сайт 1 " , " перейти на сайт рекламодателя","пойти в интернет (вбивают ссылку какую хотят)" ." только про ссылки сказано.

Comment: а как отследить когда пользователь набирает адрес назначения в адресной строке?! я так понял тс это тоже хочет отслеживать

Answer (score 1):

Логичнее было бы в дате хранить timestamp.

```
$date = time();
```

Это удобнее при работе с часовыми поясами.

Но по вашему варианту надо

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

условный оператор ИЛИ(||) в аргументе функции date() не нужен.

Comment: Уже поменял, спасибо!

Comment: Загвоздка у меня не со временем )) Мне бы разобраться с отслеживанием  url

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается? HTTP_REFERER содержит URL откуда пользователь перешел по ссылке.